# user can't log in SharePoint however he has an authorization

Tags: sharepoint-online, authorization

I'm a admin for a site in sharepoint online 365, I give an authorisation **total control** for user, however he can't access to site.but he can access in other sites.
he receives a error message:

```
Access Denied - You need permission to access this site.
```

Please, can you help me?  For your information, we did not allow in the code part for sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the permission for that user from the site using check permission ribbon button... if the user is available with appropriate permissions, remove that user from the site and re-add thru the site share option like owner, contributor or visitor.. this might work.

Please see the below URL permissions issue in SharePoint online :

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/support/administration/access-denied-or-need-permission-error-sharepoint-online-or-onedrive-for-business

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some tips besides Habibur's answer. The link he provide is useful.

Please check if the user has permission on site pages:

Open Site Pages library->Library Setting->Permission for this document library->Check Permissions, check if the user has proper permission on all the pages.

If there are unique permissions on site pages library, it may be possible for the user cannot access the home page. (While he shall be able to access other pages like site contents)